# Curl hangs after Accept

Tags: rhel, curl

I have connectivity in both ways from the client to the server as my `nc` command to port 80 gives `[tcp/http] succeeded!` in both ways.

I'm able to do curl post locally in the server. but couldn't do from the client. it hangs after Accept.

```
# curl -vvv http://abc.com/test.mpd
* About to connect() to abc.com port 80 (#0)
*   Trying abc.com... connected
* Connected to abc.com (abc.com) port 80 (#0)
> GET /test.mpd HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.27.1 zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.4.2
> Host: abc.com
> Accept: */*
>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the issue with packet size in switch ...

Everything works fine after increasing the packet size in switch.